# Доступ к удаленному компьютеру через IP

Tags: java, веб-программирование, ip, порт, windows-server-2008

Здрасьте!
Учу java, не могу решить одну проблему (пока что только одну).
Пишу мелкий проект, для публикации арендовал удаленный комп на amazon, развернул там приложение через tomcat на локальном хосте.
Как дать доступ к удаленному компу через ip-адрес?
tomcat использует 80 порт. 
Когда проверяю через cmd порт открыт. Проверял на сайте 2ip.ru - пишет что 80 порт закрыт. Брандмауэр настроил.
Третьи сутки ищу ответ, ничего найти не могу. HELP.
Может быть нужно перенаправить локальный порт на статический ip - но не нашёл как, везде пишут как это сделать в маршрутизаторе, но если у меня его там нет... (если можно инструкцию для чайников).
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: если вы арендовали сервер на AWS, там где то в настройках должны быть правила доступа к серверу, там надо разрешить 80 порт для всех протоколов для всех клиентов.

Comment: Я создал правило в брандмауэре, и в нем разрешил все для всех совсем не заботясь о безопасности. Но все равно недоступен...

Comment: я вам вот про [это](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-http-https-ec2/) говорю

Comment: Спасибо, настроил.
Попросил помощи у знакомого сисадмина, а после прочитал ваше сообщение. Вы были правы, нужно было открыть порт на моём инстансе в настройках AWS.